# How did "inmate" evolve to only apply to prisons and asylums?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

If you look at census records from the 1920s and before, dorm residents in schools, seminaries, and institutions are referred to as "inmates."  The term, then, was not limited just to prisons as today.  How did the association of the word to prisons only, evolve?  Has this evolved usage made the former, broader definition obsolete or inappropriate?

Comment: Not exclusive to prisons yet, asylums still contain inmates: (June 2013) "Exclusive: Where the inmates really do run the asylum" http://boingboing.net/2013/06/04/exclusive-where-the-inmates-r.html

Comment: It wasn't limited to institutions, either; in literature from the 19th and early 20th centuries, you commonly see *inmates* used to refer to the residents of any house.

Comment: The presumption, "limited just to prisons as today" is incorrect. And that makes the question rather preposterous.

Comment: @Kris I know of no context, in Britain today, where the term *inmate* would be used for anyone other than prisoners. The secure psychiatric establishments, once known as *lunatic asylums* such as Broadmoor, are called *hospitals* and those held there known as *patients*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to observe the evolution of *inmate* is to note the definitions that dictionaries have assigned to the term through the years. Here are the relevant ones that I have at hand.

From Samuel Johnson's *Dictionary of the English Language* (1756):

> Inmates are those that be admitted to dwell for their money jointly with another man.

From Noah Webster's *Compendious Dictionary of the English Language* (1806):

> a lodger, one who lives in the same house.

From Webster's *American Dictionary of the English Language* (1828):

> A person who lodges or dwells in the same house with another, occupying different rooms, but using the same door for passing in and out of the house.
>
> **2.** A lodger; one who lives with a family, but is not otherwise connected with it than as a lodger.

From Merriam-Webster's *American Dictionary of the English Language* (1864):

> A person who lodges or dwells in the same apartment or house with another; a fellow-lodger.

From Joseph Worcester's *Comprehensive Dictionary*, Revised Edition (1873):

> One who dwells jointly with another; a fellow-lodger; a fellow-boarder.

From Merriam-Webster's *International Dictionary* (1890):

> One who lives in the same house or apartment with another; a fellow lodger; esp., one of the occupants of an asylum, hospital, or prison; by extension, one who occupies or lodges in any place or dwelling.

From Merriam-Webster's *First Collegiate Dictionary* (1898):

> A fellow lodger; esp. an occupant of an asylum, prison, etc.; also, one who occupies or lodges in any place.

From Merriam-Webster's *Third Collegiate Dictionary* (1916):

> **1.** One who lives in the same house or apartment with another. **2.** One of a family or community occupying a single dwelling; also, one kept in an asylum, prison, etc. 3. An inhabitant.

From Merriam-Webster's *Fifth Collegiate Dictionary* (1936):

> **1.** One who lives in the same house or apartment with another. **2.** One of a family or community occupying a single dwelling or home; now esp., one kept in an institution. **3.** An inhabitant.

From Merriam-Webster's *Seventh Collegiate Dictionary* (1963):

> one of a family or other group occupying a single residence; esp: a person confined in an asylum, prison, or poorhouse

The definition of *inmate* has changed very little in the four subsequent editions of Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series.

Evidently the biggest shift in popular understanding of the term (in the United States) occurred between 1864 and 1890, when the sense of "lodger" was supplemented with a new meaning: "one of the occupants of an asylum, hospital, or prison."

I note, too, that the terms *roommate* (dated to 1770) and *housemate* (dated to circa 1810) made their Merriam-Webster's debuts in the 1890 *International Dictionary* and the 1973 *Eighth Collegiate*, respectively.

As a way of referring to a lodger or paying housemate, I think, the term *inmate* is virtually obsolete today. That sense of the word has simply been overwhelmed by the meaning "incarcerated or otherwise institutionalized occupant."

Comment: I wonder if there was some word that inmate displaced when it acquired this new meaning?

Comment: It doesn't seem you have attributed the meaning "incarcerated or otherwise institutionalized occupant" to any source yet. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kris The last five quotes mention that with *especially*.

Comment: Also @AndrewLeach That is counter to the OP's argument. Furthermore, the answer says nothing on the *how*. Or am I missing something again?

Comment: The phrase "incarcerated or otherwise institutionalized occupant" is my own formulation based on "one of the occupants of an asylum, hospital, or prison" (from 1890) and subsequent, differently worded versions of this definition; I put it into quotation marks not to ascribe it to someone else, but to distinguish it from the rest of the sentence as a definition. The original poster asked how the meaning of _inmate_ evolved, and my answer attempts to trace the evolution; I don't pretend to know why the extension of _inmate_ to refer specifically to an institutionalized occupant occurred.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that its just an euphemism much like a guard is now a "correctional officer," or a prison is an "institution."  Soft words allow society to accept holding fellow Americans captive under some bizarre theory of "rehabilitation" (another euphemism).  That was the general consensus among prisoners while I was held captive in a prison by guards as a prisoner.  We understand that an inmate was like a shipmate, or someone in a hospital, but not a prison because prisons hold prisoners, not inmates.  Who voluntarily goes to prison?  Doesn't "inmate" imply a voluntary act of becoming a mate to something?  When did prisons change to correctional institutions/facilities/centers?  Maybe there's a connection maybe not....but that's my 2 cents.

Comment: There is no implication of free will with the word inmate.  it has always been - and still is - applied to institutions of all kinds, often attended involuntarily, as stated in the question.  Remember that *shipmate* also applied to those who were press-ganged or conscripted to serve - not voluntary.  Also, hospital patients are there out of necessity, not because they want to.